# \appendix* still yields "Appendix A"

Tags: revtex

According to the official Revtex 4.1 documentation, if there's only one appendix, one can use `\appendix*` instead of `\appendix` to avoid having unnecessary letter A. However, in my case, adding `*` just prints it in the text and seem to have no effect at all. I have no idea how to debug this. What could be the problem?

**UPD:** commenting out `\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}` in the preamble makes `\appendix*` work as expected, but I need this package.

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \title{Paper}
    \date{\today}
    \maketitle

    \appendix*
    \section{Proof of X}
    Easy peasy
\end{document}
```

Extracted from `paper.log`:

```
revtex4-1.cls    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
...
revsymb4-1.sty    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
cleveref.sty    2013/12/28 v0.19 Intelligent cross-referencing
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you provide a simple example of code?

Comment: Perhaps you have used `\appendix{*}` when it should be `\appendix*`?

Comment: @egreg my preamble contains some black magic connected to the use of etex. It'll take some time until I boil the preamble down to something that can be regarded as simple

Comment: @AlanMunn nope, it is \appendix* :\

Comment: @egreg Alright, while working in simple example, I found that commenting out `\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}` makes `\appendix*` work as expected

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes. Check out a simple example I've added

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sry, it is there now

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This produces the reported incorrect output for me (TL 2015).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `\appendix` in `revtex4.cls` ends with `\@ifstar{...}{...}`, but `cleveref` adds code to the macro and so this `\@ifstar` is inefficient.

You can reinstate it at the end:

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \appto
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\appto{\appendix}{%
  \@ifstar{\def\thesection{\unskip}\def\theequation@prefix{A.}}%
          {\def\thesection{\Alph {section}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Paper}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Title}

\lipsum[1-3]

\appendix*
\section{Proof of X}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

(Note that `revtex4-1` is the most recent release.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`cleveref` appends some code to `\appendix` which breaks the starred variant provided by `revtex4.cls`.

The original version could be saved to, say, `\revappendix` and used then instead of `\appendix`. The cross-referencing can be maintained using the optional argument of `\label[appendix]{...}`, which is an invention by `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,showkeys,showpacs]{revtex4}

\let\revappendix\appendix


\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\title{Paper}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Main section} \label{mainsection}

\revappendix*
\section{Proof of X} \label[appendix]{myappsection}
Easy peasy


In \cref{mainsection} and \cref{myappsection}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's elegant, but doesn't it break some cleveref features?

Comment: @dmytro: I've tried with `\label{myappsection}` after that `\section` and `\cref{myappsection}` yields `Section`, so I would say: No, but this isn't a proof of course

Comment: Unfortunately, the downside of this approach is that referencing the appendix somewhere in the sections above yields `Section`, whereas one should see `Appendix`. It makes sense since clreveref doesn't know it is an appendix.

Comment: @dmytro: Cured ;-)